# Vim use a variable interpolated within a String?

Tags: vim, zshrc

I have a `.zshrc` and `.vimrc` file

In my `.zshrc` file I have `syncfolder="$HOME/Google Drive/Dropbox"`

I now want to reference `syncfolder` within my `.vimrc` file, is this possible (if so, how)?

Also, within my `.vimrc` file I'm sourcing lots of other files and I want to make that more efficient.

The following doesn't work:

```
let vimfolder="~/Google Drive/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/vim"

source "$vimfolder/settings.vim"
source $vimfolder/vundle.vim
source $vimfolder/mapping.vim
source $vimfolder/filetypes.vim
source $vimfolder/commands.vim
```

...I've tried multiple variants where `vimfolder` included `$HOME` and in another I've tried exporting a variable from my `.zshrc` file, like so...

```
export SYNCFOLDER=$syncfolder
```

...in the hope that I could access it from within my `.vimrc` but it didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, just create a symlink and go back to work: `$ ln -s /full/path/to/your/dropboxed/vim /full/path/to/your/home/.vim` All that sourcing doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use `:execute` to evaluate a variable in most Ex commands. Vim variables do not have a `$` prefix, those are environment variables (which you can reference from Vimscript, too):

```
execute 'source' vimfolder . '/settings.vim'
```

However, in this particular case, I'd rather add the location to `'runtimepath'` and then use `:runtime`:

```
set runtimepath+=~/Google\ Drive/Dropbox/Fresh\ Install/Shell/vim
runtime settings.vim
```

Another alternative is *symbolic links*, so you don't have change anything in your Vim setup.

Comment: Ingo Karkat thanks for the help! :-) so if I set syncfolder="$HOME/Google Drive/Dropbox" within my zshrc file I should be able to access that within my vimrc using $syncfolder right? Is that without exporting (export ABC=$syncfolder)? Do I just reference it like so: set runtimepath+=$syncfolder/Fresh\ Install/Shell/vim ?

Comment: Don't worry, I realised I had to export the value and then I could use it within my vimrc like so: set runtimepath+=$SYNCFOLDER/Fresh\ Install/Shell/vim

Comment: Vim is another process, so yes, `export` is needed. Without it, it would only be available directly in the shell.